# Error: Undefined property: EE::$view in Filename: libraries/File_field.php (Line 618) EE v2.5.5

Tags: safecracker, zoo-visitor, php-errors, safecracker-file

I have recently started to get the following error on a SafeCracker form in an ExpressionEngine v2.5.5 website.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: EE::$view
Filename: libraries/File_field.php
Line Number: 618

Fatal error: Call to a member function head_link() on a non-object in /path/to/website/system/expressionengine/libraries/File_field.php on line 618
```

The other than standard text inputs, this form also references WYGWAM, P&T Checkboxes, P&T Dropdown, VZ URL and Safecracker File. The form has worked fine in the past, so not really sure what the heck is triggering this error now.

Comment: I have the same problem with one of my SC form. I noticed that it was occurring when there is a validation error, but I didn't figured out why it raise a php error.

Comment: I am having this problem as well, with my {exp:zoo_visitor:update_form} form. It only happens when there is a validation error. I'm on EE 2.9.0 and Zoo Visitor 1.3.32, and the line number it references is '704'

Comment: Oh, also, this error DOES NOT show up if I remove the 'error_handling="inline"' from my update_form tag...

Comment: I don't use safecracker nor do I use a version that old. But what the error is telling you is that the view library is not loaded when it's trying to use it.  Is there a `browser` method that ends up calling the `_browser_css` method which is creating the error? Try `ee()->load->library('view');` somewhere in there.

Comment: How did you fare Brendon? Did the below answer help (please mark it as so if it did)? Are you still facing issues?

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that you don't have the `view` library loaded and you need it to make that call. Removing `error_handling="inline"` would prevent the errors from manipulating the view.

I'm assuming line 618 is loading css in a `_browser_css` method based on my version. That method is called by a `browser` method.  Place `ee()->load->library('view');` inside the `browser` method anywhere before the calls to the methods that require view.